# Auto Attach file using FineUploader in GMail API

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, fine-uploader

I'm trying to implement PGP file signature in my gmail account (Like "signature.asc"). I'm using FineUploader to upload my files.
But I have no idea of how to create the file and attach it.

Here is one of my numerous try :

```
var id = 0;
  var name = "signature.asc";
  var textFile;
  var data = new Blob(["TEST"], {type: 'text/plain'});
  if (textFile !== null) {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
  }
  textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

  uploader.addFiles([textFile]);
```

but my new file is considered as null by the script..

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html#addFiles), `addFiles()` expects the first argument to be __"An array of Files, <input>s, Blobs, BlobWrapper objects, <canvas>es, or CanvasWrapper objects. You may also pass in a FileList."__ So you are passing in the wrong thing, ie array of strings (object url) instead of the Blob

Comment: Obviously, thank you !